# Verilog - multiple edges in one block like in VHDL?

Tags: verilog, quartus

I'm using Quartus II, version 11.0 and I'm trying to port my VHDL code to Verilog (just for practice).

I need to check - how long 'a' line is low. There are working VHDL code:

```
process (clock, a)
begin
    -- on each rising edge of clock...
    if (rising_edge(clock))
    then -- count how long 'a' is low
        if (a = '0' and a_low_time < 3)
        then
            a_low_time <= a_low_time + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
    -- reset counter if 'a' is not low
    if a = '1' then
        a_low_time <= 0;
    end if;
end process;
```

Very simple, it's working perfectly. But how can I do it using Verilog?
This code:

```
// on each rising edge of clock...
always @ (posedge clock)
begin
    // count how long 'a' is low
    if (!a && a_low_time < 3)
        a_low_time <= a_low_time + 1;
end

// reset counter if 'a' is high
always @ (*)
begin
    if (a)
        a_low_time <= 0;
end
```

Throws "сan't resolve multiple constant drivers" error. And this:

```
always @ (posedge clock, posedge a)
begin
    if (!a && a_low_time < 3)
        a_low_time <= a_low_time + 1;
    else if (a)
        a_low_time <= 0;
end
```

Throws "cannot match operand(s) in the condition to the corresponding edges in the enclosing event control of the always construct" error.

This code is **working**:

```
always @ (posedge clock)
begin
    if (!a && a_low_time < 3)
        a_low_time <= a_low_time + 1;
    else if (a)
        a_low_time <= 0;
end
```

But I need to reset a_low_time immediately after 'a' goes high but not on rising edge of clock.

How can I do it? Can't believe that I can't do so simple task.

Comment: Already asked and answered on the EE site, read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/28369/1743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to reset a_low_time asynchronously?  In any case, maybe you can use a as your reset line:

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge a)
begin
    if (a)
        a_low_time <= 0;
    else if (!a && a_low_time < 3)
        a_low_time <= a_low_time + 1;
```

Actually, since a is your reset, you shouldn't need to check it to increment:

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge a)
begin
    if (a)
        a_low_time <= 0;
    else if (a_low_time < 3)
        a_low_time <= a_low_time + 1;
```

Comment: And I need it for MMC3 IRQ which based on A12 line: http://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/MMC3
This line is used by PPU which working asynchronously from main CPU.

Comment: @Cluster I've always thought the way the always block distinguishes between a clock line and a reset line is a bit... weird (and perhaps non-intuitive)